# Compare length of three lists in python

Tags: python

Is there a nicer way to compare the length of three lists to make sure they are all the same size besides doing comparisons between each set of variables?  What if I wanted to check the length is equal on ten lists.  How would I go about doing it?

Comment: You don't have to compare every possible pair of lists (which is `O(n!)` in the number of lists). You only need to compare the first list with all the rest of the lists (which is `O(n)`).

Comment: Equality is transitive, so once you establish that two of them are equal, pick one and compare each of the remaining lists to that one.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python, so i don't really know how to use generators or any of that fancy stuff to do something like this.

Comment: I would just do a bunch of if comparisons normally...

Comment: @chepner And, of course, if two of them are *not* equal, then you can stop.

Comment: Note that `x == y == z` works as expected in python ..

Comment: @wim i've just tried that in python 2.7 and it doesn't work with lists the same size with different values only lists the same size with the same values!

Comment: @Wooble I know that. I was just saying works as expected isn't a length compare (in reference to the question)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
length = len(list1)
if all(len(lst) == length for lst in [list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]):
    # all lists are the same length
```

Or to find out if any of the lists have a different length:

```
length = len(list1)
if any(len(lst) != length for lst in [list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]):
    # at least one list has a different length
```

Note that `all()` and `any()` will short-circuit, so for example if `list2` has a different length it will not perform the comparison for `list3` through `list6`.

If your lists are stored in a list or tuple instead of separate variables:

```
length = len(lists[0])
if all(len(lst) == length for lst in lists[1:]):
    # all lists are the same length
```

Comment: so if i wanted to find any list that didn't equal the length for the other ones, would i just change the `len(lst) == length` to `len(lst) != length`?

Comment: You could use `if not all(len(lst) == length ...)` or `if any(len(lst) != length ...)` to find out if any list has a different length.  Or do you actually need to know which lists have different lengths?

Comment: No, just need to verify that they are all equal.  I just don't like using `if/else` if i can just use `if`

Comment: Okay I edited my answer to include that.  You will either want to use `if not all(...)` with `==` or `if any(...)` with `!=`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your lists are stored in a list (called `my_lists`), use something like this:

```
print len(set(map(len, my_lists))) <= 1
```

This calculates the lengths of all the lists you have in `my_lists` and puts these lengths into a set. If they are all the same, the set is going to contain one element (or **zero you have no lists**).

Comment: why <1 ... maybe you meant ==1

Comment: Because if `my_lists` is empty, i.e. you are checking to see if the lengths of zero lists are the same, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Then it only works for an empty list.

Comment: yes indeed, just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

One liner using `itertools.combinations()`

```
import itertools

l1 = [3,4,5]
l2 = [4,5,7]
l3 = [5,6,7,8,3]

L = [l1, l2, l3]

verdict = all([len(a)==len(b) for a,b in list(itertools.combinations(L,2))])
```

First build list of list, `L`. Then query all sets of two elements from L, with `list(itertools.combinations(L,2))`:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(L,2))
[([3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 7]), ([3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 3]), 
           ([4, 5, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8, 3])]
```

Then test lengths for each pair in this list. Finally, take intersection of the booleans, with `all()`.

```
>>> verdict
False
```

Which is correct. Let's try with try lists of the same size.

```
l1 = [3,4,5]
l2 = [4,5,7]
l3 = [5,6,7]

L = [l1, l2, l3]

verdict=all([len(a)==len(b) for a,b in list(itertools.combinations(L,2))])
```

we get

```
>>> verdict
True
```

Comment: FYI this is terrible? == is totally transitive, so building all the combinations, especially if you would be comparing many lists, is super inefficient.