# how to recursively compare 2 lists in python (unsorted, order-independent)

Tags: python, list, recursion, compare

The last issue I have is being able to accurately compare two lists of the same size that have no elements in common. I cannot use any built in Python functions (i.e., sort, compare, Counter) except for list methods len, del, index.

My code:

```
def SameStuff(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) <= 1 or len(l2) <= 1 or len(l1) != len(l2):
        if len(l1) == 0 or len(l2) == 0:   
            return len(l1) == len(l2)
        else:                    
            return len(l1) == len(l2) and l1[0] == l2[0]     
    else:
        if l1[0] == l2[0]:                                          
            return SameStuff(l1[1:], l2[1:])                 
        else:
            return SameStuff(l1, l2[1:]+[l2[0]])
```

Comment: order-INDEPENDENT

Comment: check this similar question [Compare length of three lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720844/compare-length-of-three-lists-in-python). Must it be done "recursively" ?

Comment: also what's wrong with the code you have here? Does it not accomplish your goal? Does it produce any errors that you can include in the question...and what *is* your question?

Comment: Yes, I must use recursion. The only test case it does not pass is if the lists have no common elements (i.e., [1,2] and [3,4]) because my recursive step only decrements the length if they have a term in common. The purpose of the function is to return True if the lists are equivalent (order-independent) and False otherwise.

Comment: Very close, but mine has to be able to work with order independence. [1,2,5] == [2,1,5] so I cannot just test the first element over and over.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def SameStuff(l1, l2):
        if l1 == []: return l2 == []
        if len(l1) != len(l2): return False
        else: return SameStuff(l1[1:], [x for x in l2 if x != l1[0]])
```

This works order independently.

And the following version allows also repetitions of elements in the lists.

```
def SameStuff(l1, l2):
    if l1 == []: return l2 == []    
    elif len(l1) != len(l2): return False  
    elif l1[0] in l2: 
        i = l2.index(l1[0]) 
        return SameStuff(l1[1:], l2[:i] + l2[i+1:]) 
    else: return False
```

Comment: This isn't strictly a boolean predicate as it returns `True`, `False` or `None`.  It should also be noted that it can be destructive on 'l2' -- itself not a criticism, just something one should comment.

Comment: @cdlane: but you wrote one is allowed only to use `len`, `del`, `index` - well I used `in` in addition ... but if you don't want it to be destructive, sure one could copy everytime the entire list ... by l[:] ... can you show me a case where it returns None? All return valures are boolean. `l2 == []` is a boolean

Comment: eliminated `in` and `del` by list expression - which also removes the destructive side effect.

Comment: As far as `None` is concerned, in your original code, if you passed two equal length lists with different elements, say `SameStuff([1], [2])`, it would fall through all the 'if` clauses and fall out the bottom of the function, returning `None`.  That's been eliminated in your revision.

Comment: I didn't write that "one is allowed only to use `len`, `del`, `index`", the OP did.  I was simply following that direction.  I also didn't express any desire for it to be destructive or non-destructive, it's simply something one documents if it is destructive.  The inclusion of `del()` indicates the instructor probably expected a destructive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is confusing:

> compare two lists of the same size that have no elements in common

How do you compare lists that have nothing in common?  It seems like you want to compare two lists to see if they contain the same elements, but in any order.  As far as doing it only with the functions/methods `len()`, `del()`, and `index()`, I believe it can be done with just `index()`:

```
def SameStuff(l1, l2):
    if l1 and l2:  # both contain something
        try:
            index = l2.index(l1[0])

            return SameStuff(l1[1:], l2[:index] + l2[1 + index:])  # recurse

        except ValueError:

            return False  # a value in one wasn't found in the other

    return not(l1 or l2)  # only one contains something (False), or neither do (True)
```

This solution is also not destructive to its arguments.

Comment: very good! I was just not sure if `try` and except` are allowed. And true `no elements in common` is wrongly expressed. `no element positions in common, perhaps`?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to compare 2 lists with no regard to order is with `collections.Counter` as it takes an average time complexity of just O(n), but since you can't use it, you can instead implement the same principal on your own using two dicts to keep track of the counts of each distinct item in each list:

```
def compare(l1, l2, d1=None, d2=None):
    if not d1:
        d1, d2 = {}, {}
    if l1 and l2:
        d1[l1.pop()] = d1.get(l1[-1], 0) + 1
        d2[l2.pop()] = d2.get(l2[-1], 0) + 1
        return compare(l1, l2, d1, d2)
    elif not l1 and not l2:
        return d1 == d2
    return False
```

so that:

```
print(compare([2, 3, 5, 3], [3, 5, 2, 3]))
print(compare([2, 3, 5, 2], [3, 5, 2, 3]))
print(compare([2, 3, 5, 2], [3, 5, 2]))
```

would output:

```
True
False
False
```

Note that any approach that slices a list or uses `list.index` is always going to be inefficient because it takes O(n) to do each of those for every item in the lists, resulting in O(n^2) overall time complexity.

Comment: `pop()` isn't an allowed list method, i.e. `len()`, `del()`, and `index()`.  But we all bent the rules. Your solution, with lists of same length, has to recurse both completely before deciding they're different.  I tested if extra recursion overhead overcomes dictionary efficiency if the lists are long. (Increasing recursion depth sufficiently) your dictionary clearly won out, to a point.  Your solution did a `Segmentation fault` as the number of elements approached 17,000 though my `index()` solution continued to work.  You also need to document that `l1` can't point to the same list as `l2`.