# Check if the elements and length of two unsorted lists are equal using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I am trying to write a purely recursive function that will return True if two unsorted lists are of the same length and contain the same elements. I am not allowed to use any iteration, only recursion. Here is an example of what it should do:

```
>>> SameStuff(['Hello',1,2,3],[3,2,1,'Hello'])
True
>>> SameStuff(['HELLO',1,2,3],[3,'two',1,'Hello'])
False
>>> SameStuff([1,2],[])
False
```

I am struggling with the logic of my recursive function, and am missing some elements. Here's what I have:

```
def SameStuff(list1,list2):
    if len(list1)!=len(list2):
        return False
    if #some base case:
        #return True?
    if list1[0] in list2:
        return SameStuff(list1[1:],list2)
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Presumably the base case is that both lists are empty

Comment: What do you mean by "unordered list"?  Lists are inherently ordered.  Do you mean _unsorted_?

Comment: The first and the third case together mean that this cannot work. As soon as you call the function with one element removed from *one* list, it will return False.

Comment: @mkrieger - yes, that recursive case is wrong as it stands. I don't think you can do it in a 1-liner either. But that's all that needs fixing, other than adding the base case where both lists are empty.

Comment: To write a recursive function, start with the particular cases (empty lists, list of one element, etc.) and then the nominal case.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52826662/5771269) from 2 days ago but I can't vote to "close as duplicate" as the previous has no upvoted answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have most of the logic in the right place. You are just missing the case when both will be empty, by then presumably they were the same lists in different (potentially) orders!

Probably not efficient with the remove function, but tricky to pop the same elements from two different unordered lists.

```
def SameStuff(l1, l2):
    if not l1 and not l2:
        return True

    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False

    last_element = l1[-1]
    if last_element not in l2:
        return False

    l1.remove(last_element)
    l2.remove(last_element)

    return SameStuff(l1, l2)
```

Comment: This also alters the original lists. If they contained the same stuff, we might never know if they were empty to begin with or not :)

Comment: Also, `.remove` is implicit iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure if the point about the lists being empty to begin with truly matters for this use case. OP only wants to know if they were of the same length and had the same elements. The point about remove is fair. How would you suggest tackling removal of the same item between two different lists without iteration?

Comment: OP said "are of the same length and contain the same elements" (emphasis on "are" :) Not sure items necessarily need to be removed from the lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
def SameStuff(list1, list2):

    # if both empty, they are equal
    if not list1 and not list2:
        return True

    # if unequal lengths, they are not equal
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False

    # grab the first item from list1
    item = list1[0]

    # if it isn't in list2, they are not equal
    if item not in list2:
        return False

    # make copies so we don't disturb the original lists
    newlist1 = list1[:]
    newlist2 = list2[:]

    # remove the item from both copies
    newlist1.remove(item)
    newlist2.remove(item)

    # call ourself with the list copies
    return SameStuff(newlist1, newlist2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def SameStuff(l1, l2):
    if l1 == []: return l2 == []    # if recursed down to empty lists -> True
    elif len(l1) != len(l2): return False   # if any length differences -> False
    elif l1[0] in l2: 
        i = l2.index(l1[0]) # identify index of first in l2 identical to l1[0]
        return SameStuff(l1[1:], l2[:i] + l2[i+1:]) # l2 without this element!
    else: return False
```

This works independent from order.
And also if there are multiple occurrences of some elements.

Comment: I don't believe your `else` clause works when both lists contain multiple copies of `list1[0]`.  Only one copy will be removed from list1, but all copies will be removed from list2.

Comment: @John Gordon: True! I have to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @John Gordon: Now it is fixed also for repetitive elements in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to state that the missing base case in your code is test if both lists are empty.

The other important factor, is avoid to remove the found element from any of both received list, since that could alter them after the call.

This is the same code than yours, with the least modifications possible in my opinion:

```
def SameStuff(list1,list2):                                                   
    if len(list1)!=len(list2):
        return False
    if len(list1) == 0 and len(list2) == 0:
        return True
    if list1[0] in list2:
        list2b = list2[:]
        list2b.remove(list1[0])
        return SameStuff(list1[1:], list2b)
    else:
        return False


print(SameStuff(['Hello',1,2,3], [3,2,1,'Hello']))
print(SameStuff(['HELLO',1,2,3],[3,'two',1,'Hello']))
print(SameStuff([1,2],[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to **not make any loop,** you can add a parameter in the input of your function:

```
def SameStuff(list1,list2,i):
    if list1==[] and list2==[]:
        return True

    elif i>=len(list1):
        return False

    elif len(list1)!=len(list2):
        return False

    elif list1[i]==list2[0]:
        del list1[i]
        del list2[0]
        return SameStuff(list1,list2,0)
    else:
        return SameStuff(list1,list2,i+1)


print(SameStuff(["hello",1,4],[1,3,"hello"],0))
print(SameStuff(["hello",1,3],[1,3,"hello"],0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def SameStuff(l1, l2):
    if l1 and l2:  # both contain something
        try:
            index = l2.index(l1[0])

            return SameStuff(l1[1:], l2[:index] + l2[1 + index:])  # recurse

        except ValueError:

            return False  # a value in one wasn't found in the other

    return not(l1 or l2)  # only one contains something (False), or neither do (True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to insert three more default parameters (those would not be needed for the first function call): an empty dictionary, an integer index, and a boolean.

Use the boolean to indicate which list we are traversing and the index to point to the current list element (we could also just use a sign on the index instead of the boolean). When traversing the first list, record in the dictionary the count of each unique element encountered, using the element as key. At the end, flip the boolean and traverse the second list, this time subtracting from the counts of elements in the dictionary. Remove any elements reaching zero counts. Assuming we've already tested for matching list lengths, if an element is not found in the dictionary, the lists do not match.